# How to open android activity from webiview?

Tags: javascript, java, android

How do I open a specific android activity from a click inside the webpage which is integrated using webview??

I want to pass data through that link for that activity too..

Comment: from a website, website? or from a webview from within your app?

Comment: the button is in my website, and I want that button to open a specific activity in my app @DroiDev . That website is loaded in a webview (different activity)

Comment: you want to look into "deeplink" https://developers.tune.com/sdk/deep-linking-to-your-mobile-app-from-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

This Concept Is Of Deeplinks You Can Achieve This Using

> Firebase's DynamicLinks

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can add a java script interface to webview which is called within java script in your webview and implements some logic in your native code base. As a result you listen to some event from java script and do what you need in your activity or fragment or any component that is hosting webview in itself